# Cocoa - Launching a child process?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstask

What is the best method to use for launching a child process?

Namely, I want to launch a webview for a limited time - due to memory usage I'd like to run this as a child process.

Is NSTask suitable for this?

And how does one specify that one app is to be a child process for another? Right now I have two separate xcode projects. One that is to launch the webview, and the other is simply the webview itself.

Ideally the parent app should be notified when the child (helper) app quits.

Any tips on designing this?

Comment: Why does it need to be a separate process? Why not just make it a window owned by the same app?

Comment: Just use NSTimer if needed or gauge the memory usage.